# Hide an element if another element contains certain text

Tags: jquery

We want the "Apply for this Fund" button disabled when the Fund Details has Status: Closed, like this: https://i.imgur.com/otHCrxo.png.

The problem we have is that when Status has "Open", even then, the Apply for this Fund (`#btn-apply`) will be hidden.

So `:contains('Closed')` is not working properly for some reason.

```js
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function($){
        setTimeout(function () {
            if($("#fund-details .listing_detail.col-md-4.status:contains('Closed')")) {
                $("#btn-apply").hide();
            };
        }, 1000);
    });
})( jQuery );
```

```html
<div id="fund-details">
  <div class="listing_detail col-md-4 status text-green"><strong>Status:</strong> Open</div>
</div>

<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-3ebb592 elementor-align-center elementor-widget__width-inherit elementor-widget elementor-widget-button" data-id="3ebb592" data-element_type="widget" id="btn-apply" data-widget_type="button.default" style="display: none;">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
      <div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
          <a class="elementor-button elementor-button-link elementor-size-md elementor-animation-push" href="http://applications.silcgroup.com/the-silc-group/mosaic-capital-fund.php" o-123link="">
                <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
                  <span class="elementor-button-text">Apply for this                                                            Fund</span>
                </span>
          </a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-650b37c7 elementor-align-center elementor-widget__width-inherit elementor-widget elementor-widget-button" data-id="650b37c7" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="button.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
                   <a class="elementor-button elementor-button-link elementor-size-md elementor-animation-push" href="https://silcgroup.com/" o-123link="">
               <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
                <span class="elementor-button-text">Fund Manager</span>
              </span>
                    </a>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: The `id="btn-apply"` element has `style="display: none;"` in the *HTML*, so it's not going to be visible until/unless you have code that removes that (perhaps via a [`show`](https://api.jquery.com/show/) call). You might also look at [`toggle`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) which you can pass a boolean into. In all of those cases, though, I'd suggest showing and hiding using a class, not inline CSS, and I'd do it on some kind of action (page load, something changing, etc.) rather than on a timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id="btn-apply"` element has `style="display: none;"` in the *HTML*, so it's not going to be visible until/unless you have code that removes that (perhaps via a [`show`](https://api.jquery.com/show/) call). You might also look at [`toggle`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) which you can pass a boolean into. In all of those cases, though, I'd suggest showing and hiding using a class, not inline CSS, and I'd do it on some kind of action (page load, something changing, etc.) rather than on a timer.

Also, `$("#fund-details .listing_detail.col-md-4.status:contains('Closed')")` returns a jQuery object, which is always truthy, not a flag. You could remove the CSS pseudo-class and get the text, then use `includes` on it. (Or check `.length`, which will be `0` if no elements matched.)

Here's a minimal-changes example using `toggle`:

```js
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function($){
        setTimeout(function () {
            const closed = $("#fund-details .listing_detail.col-md-4.status").text().includes("Closed");
            $("#btn-apply").toggle(!closed);
        }, 1000);
    });
})( jQuery );
```

```html
<div id="fund-details">
  <div class="listing_detail col-md-4 status text-green"><strong>Status:</strong> Open</div>
</div>

<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-3ebb592 elementor-align-center elementor-widget__width-inherit elementor-widget elementor-widget-button" data-id="3ebb592" data-element_type="widget" id="btn-apply" data-widget_type="button.default" style="display: none;">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
      <div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
          <a class="elementor-button elementor-button-link elementor-size-md elementor-animation-push" href="http://applications.silcgroup.com/the-silc-group/mosaic-capital-fund.php" o-123link="">
                <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
                  <span class="elementor-button-text">Apply for this                                                            Fund</span>
                </span>
          </a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-650b37c7 elementor-align-center elementor-widget__width-inherit elementor-widget elementor-widget-button" data-id="650b37c7" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="button.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
                   <a class="elementor-button elementor-button-link elementor-size-md elementor-animation-push" href="https://silcgroup.com/" o-123link="">
               <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
                <span class="elementor-button-text">Fund Manager</span>
              </span>
                    </a>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

But again, I really wouldn't do this on a timer.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. It works [here](https://staging.silc.co/investments/brisbane-series-4-units/) but [not here](https://staging.silc.co/investments/adelaide-cbd-landmark-fund/).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with your code:

1. You don't do the reverse but initially you hide the button, you need to show this in your else statement.
2. <s>It's a bit safer to use jQuery to get the text vs css contains, as this is more widely supported.</s>

**As clarified in the comments, it IS safe to use as jQuery ensures cross-browser compatibility. This is just another approach how you could get text out of your selected element.**

```js
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function($){
        setTimeout(function () {
            if($("#fund-details .listing_detail.col-md-4.status").first().text() === 'Status: Closed') {
                $("#btn-apply").hide();
            } else {
                $("#btn-apply").show();
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
})( jQuery );
```

```html
<div id="fund-details">
  <div class="listing_detail col-md-4 status text-green"><strong>Status:</strong> Open</div>
</div>

<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-3ebb592 elementor-align-center elementor-widget__width-inherit elementor-widget elementor-widget-button" data-id="3ebb592" data-element_type="widget" id="btn-apply" data-widget_type="button.default" style="display: none;">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
      <div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
          <a class="elementor-button elementor-button-link elementor-size-md elementor-animation-push" href="http://applications.silcgroup.com/the-silc-group/mosaic-capital-fund.php" o-123link="">
                <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
                  <span class="elementor-button-text">Apply for this                                                            Fund</span>
                </span>
          </a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-650b37c7 elementor-align-center elementor-widget__width-inherit elementor-widget elementor-widget-button" data-id="650b37c7" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="button.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div class="elementor-button-wrapper">
                   <a class="elementor-button elementor-button-link elementor-size-md elementor-animation-push" href="https://silcgroup.com/" o-123link="">
               <span class="elementor-button-content-wrapper">
                <span class="elementor-button-text">Fund Manager</span>
              </span>
                    </a>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: jQuery provides [`:contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), so it's safe to use if you're going to use jQuery. It's not really helpful here, I'd do something else as you have, but it's reliable. :-)